# methods available for draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have dragged a node from TreeView and dropped it by alerting the Text of the node as `alert(ui.draggable.text());` How will I get the Value of the dragged node ? What all methods are there for draggable other than `text()` ?

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head><title>
    Untitled Page
</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui.draggable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/ui.droppable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .dragcss { width: 75px; height: 25px; background: silver; padding: 10px; }
        .dropcss { position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 0; width: 125px; height: 75px; background: gray; color: white; padding: 10px; }
        .dropcss1 { width: 325px; height: 205px; background: beige; color: black; }
        .treeNode { color:blue; font:14px Arial, Sans-Serif; }
        .rootNode { font-size:18px; width:100%; border-bottom:Solid 1px black; }
        .leafNode { border:Dotted 2px black; padding:4px; background-color:#eeeeee; font-weight:bold; }
    </style>

<style type="text/css">
    .ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 { text-decoration:none; }
    .ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1 { border-style:none; }
    .ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2 {  }

</style></head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="DragDropTreeView1.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ExpandState" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ExpandState" value="eennnennn" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_SelectedNode" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_SelectedNode" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_PopulateLog" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_PopulateLog" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTIwMDg4MDIyNDYPZBYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICAw9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPPCsACQIADxYGHg1OZXZlckV4cGFuZGVkZB4MU2VsZWN0ZWROb2RlZB4JTGFzdEluZGV4AglkCBQrAAJkFCsAAhYCHghFeHBhbmRlZGcUKwADZBQrAAIWAh8DZxQrAARkFCsAAhYCHwNnZBQrAAIWAh8DZ2QUKwACFgIfA2dkFCsAAhYCHwNnFCsABGQUKwACFgIfA2dkFCsAAhYCHwNnZBQrAAIWAh8DZ2RkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBS5jdGwwMCRTYW1wbGVNYXN0ZXJDb250ZW50UGxhY2VIb2xkZXIkVHJlZVZpZXcxkLfNjG/12TUIpgO1ZyU1Ry9g7Dg=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=nf5uDZf9LhRa-ij6_ln32g2&amp;t=634115066046333750" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=-_Z2ZXavdO8Ezg-kA84ZvmVgjjSyjH6mPKq7ZZM1cz2uLwlXWnF7MVaFwkbzWADj9wN6LEk5ihQlv_D6OQDj8g2&amp;t=fffffffff2a422d9" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

    function TreeView_PopulateNodeDoCallBack(context,param) {
        WebForm_DoCallback(context.data.treeViewID,param,TreeView_ProcessNodeData,context,TreeView_ProcessNodeData,false);
    }
var ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data = null;//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=jkNSjYNc7Ub-HtvpZnNG7VeJ9LnQr6hZziD0_aghfOMBGWOZKfV7wYRMwK6o5lKehE2Y_ZQTdK10_EV6DTo4--h_EUfAyv59eyc6aGvwRSc1&amp;t=254510a4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=jkNSjYNc7Ub-HtvpZnNG7VeJ9LnQr6hZziD0_aghfOMBGWOZKfV7wYRMwK6o5lKelL3Mb7rpaOxs3dWQVgyhR6580N9mVlhyBdmh95dXpL8_nElyKM90269LCazuYNqr0&amp;t=254510a4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCgKjp6i9CwKUteWiCwLPxJrcCwLUz4yaBAKsk4WVBAKhpf64AgLPxNbtAQLN+pTEAwKsk+HaCQKupb6kAXaDkRVw5gFckQsP1zMUeyTYU1b7" />
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$sc', document.getElementById('aspnetForm'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls(['tctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$upnlFirst'], [], [], 90);
//]]>
</script>

    <div>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $("#ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1 a.treeNode").draggable({
                appendTo: 'body',
                helper: 'clone',
                start: function(event, ui) {

                    var previousTd = $(this).parent().prev();
                    $("img", previousTd).css("visibility", "hidden");
                },
                stop: function(event, ui) {
                    var previousTd = $(this).parent().prev();
                    $("img", previousTd).css("visibility", "visible");
                },
                zIndex: '100'
            });

            $(".droppable").droppable({
                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    alert(ui.draggable.text());
                    alert(ui.draggable.attr("Value"));
                }
            });
        });


    </script>

    <div id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_upnlFirst">

            <table id="tblMain" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%">
                        <a href="#ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links." src="/WebResource.axd?d=_aOWHcaWhikpJlYso1Bk8A2&amp;t=634115066046333750" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tr>
                <td><a id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n0" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data,0,ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n0,' ',ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n0Nodes)"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97W_JvLDnMdpzyC2xLju6gYY1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="Collapse Employees" style="border-width:0;" /></a></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t0');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t0" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Employees</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table><div id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n0Nodes" style="display:block;">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n1" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data,1,ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n1,' ',ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n1Nodes)"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97W_JvLDnMdpzyC2xLju6gYY1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="Collapse HR" style="border-width:0;" /></a></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass1')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t1');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t1" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">HR</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table><div id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n1Nodes" style="display:block;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="" /></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass1\\ID-1234')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t2');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t2" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Bradley</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="" /></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass1\\ID-5678')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t3');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t3" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Whitney</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="" /></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass1\\ID-9101')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t4');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t4" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Barbara</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n5" href="javascript:TreeView_ToggleNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data,5,ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n5,' ',ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n5Nodes)"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97W_JvLDnMdpzyC2xLju6gYY1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="Collapse IT" style="border-width:0;" /></a></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass2')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t5');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t5" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">IT</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table><div id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1n5Nodes" style="display:block;">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="" /></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass2\\ID-5587')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t6');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t6" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Jimmy</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="" /></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass2\\ID-5474')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t7');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t7" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Samantha</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&amp;t=634115066046333750" alt="" /></td><td class="treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_2" style="white-space:nowrap;"><a class="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_0 treeNode ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1','sEmployees\\SubClass2\\ID-2001')" onclick="TreeView_SelectNode(ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data, this,'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t8');" id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1t8" style="border-style:none;font-size:1em;">Freddy</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><a id="ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_SkipLink"></a>

                     </td>
                    <td style="width:50%" valign="top">
                        <div id="content" class='droppable' style='height: 200px;width:200px;background-color:Aqua;'>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>   

</div>  

    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ImageArray =  new Array('', '', '', '/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97UsXKuAflR8TNlHOiqqEj1w1&t=634115066046333750', '/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97flu4JJFpcZbBEsvyw9YUW81&t=634115066046333750', '/WebResource.axd?d=3_lvwIPQNzTdTcWf7tk97W_JvLDnMdpzyC2xLju6gYY1&t=634115066046333750');
//]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

WebForm_InitCallback();var ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data = new Object();
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.images = ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ImageArray;
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.collapseToolTip = "Collapse {0}";
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.expandToolTip = "Expand {0}";
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.expandState = theForm.elements['ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ExpandState'];
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.selectedNodeID = theForm.elements['ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_SelectedNode'];
for (var i=0;i<6;i++) {
var preLoad = new Image();
if (ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ImageArray[i].length > 0)
preLoad.src = ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ImageArray[i];
}
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.lastIndex = 9;
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.populateLog = theForm.elements['ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_PopulateLog'];
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.treeViewID = 'ctl00$SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder$TreeView1';
ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data.name = 'ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data';
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._registerDisposeScript("ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_upnlFirst", "ctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_ImageArray.length = 0;\r\nctl00_SampleMasterContentPlaceHolder_TreeView1_Data = null;");
Sys.Application.initialize();
//]]>
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ui.draggable`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable) is the jquery object representing the dragged DOM element...[all the jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/) are available on it :)

For example to get an attribute:

```
ui.draggable.attr('data-value')
```

or if it's an input type element:

```
ui.draggable.val()
```

I can't say exactly without knowing what your draggable is...but it's the same way you'd get it if it *weren't* a draggable.

Comment: its not working. I mean I am not getting the Value of the node

Comment: @Sreejesh - You're not being very clear about "the value of the node"...can you post your markup?  Without knowing what your HTML looks like, no one can give you an exact answer.  You should add to the question the markup, and what in it you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: I had addedthe HTMl to the question

Comment: @Sreejesh - That's not the HTML, that's the ASPX :) Can you post the *rendered* HTML? That's all your JavaScript will care about.

Comment: And here, I want to retrieve both Text and Value of the Child nodes only. ie I want to drag only the child nodes only.

Comment: @Sreejesh - Your selector should be `td.treeNode` for `.draggable()` based on the markup, then `.text()` will work.  The value you can't get, it's not rendered onto the page, it's a value that ASP.Net uses server-side (stored in ViewState).

Comment: So how will we retrieve the value part at server side ? Coz I need both Text and Value for processing.

Comment: @Sreejesh - I *strongly* suggest you look at an alternative like [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/).  The ASP.Net treeview renders horrible markup, and blending client/server is messy at best, you should either go with a postback model and leave out `.draggable()` (using a third party treeview control, that's a server control) or use something like jsTree and do the postbacks from it, where you can fully control your rendering and values.  Your page will be more functional and lighter at the same time.